# C# Adding data to combo-box from MS Access table

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and am creating a test app to populate a combo-box from a table within an Access database.  I want to be able to set this information on the fly.  As a tester, I have created a new form, added a single combo-box called "TBCallOutcome", and added the code.

However, it seems to populate the drop-down with "System.Data.DataRowView" in every row.

Any ideas - thank you?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "SELECT [Call outcome] FROM [DD Call Outcomes] WHERE ((([Show on list])=True)) ORDER BY [Sort order]";
        OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='N:\\Test\\Dropdowns.mdb';User Id=admin; Password=;");
        DataTable source = new DataTable();
        dAdapter.Fill(source);
        TBCallOutcome.DataSource = source;
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to set `DisplayMember` for `ComboBox`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "SELECT [Call outcome] FROM [DD Call Outcomes] WHERE ((([Show on list])=True)) ORDER BY [Sort order]";
    OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='N:\\Test\\Dropdowns.mdb';User Id=admin; Password=;");
    DataTable source = new DataTable();
    dAdapter.Fill(source);

    TBCallOutcome.ValueMember = "[Call outcome]";
    TBCallOutcome.DisplayMember = "[Call outcome]";
    TBCallOutcome.DataSource = source;
}
```